# Socket.io + node.js + routes

Tags: javascript, socket.io

there is an application in vue and a node server with socket.io
How can I pass an already connected socket from socket.io to the controller when I make a post request from the application to the server?

I tried declaring global.io=io but the socket is still undefined
io.socket.join(room_id); (undefined)

server.js

```
var app = require('express');
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
const port = 3002;

const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const routes = require('./routes/routes');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true,}));
app.use(cors());
app.use('/api', routes);
global.io = io;
//Start the server
server.listen(port, (error) => {
    if (error) return console.log(`Error: ${error}`);
    console.log(`Server listening on port ${server.address().port}`);
});

//Sockets on
io.sockets.on('connection', (socket) => {
    //User connected
    console.log("A user connected");
    ......
});
```

controller.js

```
const pool = require('../data/config');
const validator = require('validator');
const auth = require('../models/jwtModel');
const errors = require('../data/errors');

module.exports = {

        games: function(req, res){ 
            ...
        },
        create: function(req, res){
            ...
        },
        join : function(req, res){
            //got a number
            //other actions
            ......
            //does not work
            //you need to attach the current socket to this room and send a message to this room
            //How can a connected socket be passed from the server.js?
            socket.join(room_id);
            io.sockets.in(room_id).emit('room.change',{type:"room.start"});
            res.status(200).send({code: 0, room_id: room_id});                       
        },
        leave : function(req, res){
            ...
        },
}
```

routes.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var controller = require('../controllers/controller');
router.route('/controller').post(controller.join);


module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0):

To initial socket.

> Try this

```
import express from "express";
import http from "http";
import cors from "cors";

const app = express()
// obvious you need have bodyParse and cors
const server = http.createServer(app)
const io = new Server(server, {
 cors: {
     origin: "*" // to allow socket with back and front by localhost or host
  }
})

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  socket.on("join_room", async (room) => {
   console.log(`User ${socket.id} joined room ${room}`);
   socket.join(room)

  })
})


function ioEmmit({ key, data }) {
  io.emit(key, data);
  console.log("key", key);
  console.log("data", data);
}

export default ioEmmit
```

> your post route

```
import ioEmmit from "../app.js"
router.post("/", (req, res) => {
  const data = req.body
  ioEmmit({key: "identify_key", data: data}) // you can pass a object as data
})
```

Comment: But I need to join when the user sends a post request, that is, in any case, I need to join the room in the controller and no new connection was created

Comment: You can create a function called ioEmmit( { key, data} ) where you create the connection and export this function, and use the io.emit of socket when this send a post.